# Support of a $L^2$ function as a distribution.

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory

For a
$$f \in L^2(\mathbb{R})=L^2(\mathbb{R})^*
\subset D^*$$
so we can regard it as a distribution.

So we have support set of f as a distribution.
$$supp f=\{x\in \mathbb{R}: \text{for any open neighborhood U of x , restrictions of f on U is not }0\}.$$

Actually $f \in L^2$  as a function we have
$$Supp f=\overline{\{x\in \mathbb{R}:f(x) \neq 0\}}$$
But they are different.
For example ,$f(x)=1$,when x is rational,otherwise $f=0$.
For f as a distribution we have $supp f$ is empty,but $Supp f$ is the $\mathbb{R}$.

Here is my question:
For a nonnegative function $f\in L^2$ , do we have $f>0 \quad a.e$ on its support set $supp f$.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: For $f\in  L^2$, and given some $x$, saying $f(x)\neq 0$ makes no sense.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam Yes，it is a equivalent class,but for a fixed function，we can always do . And here my question only relates the support of distribution .

Comment: @reuns Yes, and its zero set is a 0 measure set.

Comment: @reuns I’m afraid not,my question is whether $f>0$ a.e on its support,which means we can admit it has a 0 measured set on its support.

Answer (score 1):

Look at $$f=\sum_{n\ge 1}\sum_{k =0}^{2^n} 1_{\displaystyle [\frac{k}{2^n}-\frac1{2^{2n+2}},\frac{k}{2^n}+\frac1{2^{2n+2}}]} \in L^2[0,1]$$

$f\ge 1$ on a neighborhood of each $k/2^n$ so $$supp(f)= [0,1]$$ but $f$ vanishes on the set with non-zero measure $$[0,1] - \bigcup_{k,n}(\frac{k}{2^n}-\frac1{2^{2n+2}},\frac{k}{2^n}+\frac1{2^{2n+2}})$$

($f>0$ a.e. on its support means that $\mu(f^{-1}(0)\cap supp(f)) = 0$ right ?)

Comment: What about f(1/2)?

Comment: The series for $f$ converges in $L^2[0,1]$, if you don't like that $f(1/2)=\infty$ then replace $k$ by $2k+1$ or take $\min(f,1)$.

Comment: Yes,this function does work,but I was troubled with $ supp f=[0,1] $.Could you explain more details?

Comment: An open $U$ around $x$ contains some $k/2^n$ so $\int_U f(y)dy \ge 2^{-2m-1}$ for some $m$

Comment: I think I can get your point,thank you so much.